# Transform from [[Char]] to own data type in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, type-conversion

```
scanl (\exp y -> scanl (\x -> if (isLetter x) then update exp (Literal x) "" else 
                    if x=='+' then update exp Epsilon "+" else
                    if x=='*' then update exp Epsilon "*" else
                    update exp Epsilon "|") y) Epsilon q
```

My data type is:

```
data Reg = Epsilon | Literal Char | Or Reg Reg |  Then Reg Reg |  Star Reg  deriving Eq
```

and

```
update:: Reg -> Reg -> [Char] -> Reg 
update a b "" = (a `Then` b)
update a b "|"= (a `Or` b) 
update a b "*" = (Star a) 
update a b "+" = (plus a)
update a b "?" = (opt a)
```

And I am trying to transform something like this ["a|","bc"] to (Then a (Or b c)) using the functions above and i can't use ParSec .

Comment: Why a list of `String`s and not one single `String`? And by what rule should the things be combined? (If you `concat` the list of `String`s to obtain `"a|bc"`, that would rather translate to `Then (Or a b) c` [or possibly `Or a (Then b c)`].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this "manually", it will end up in a mess. Instead learn how to use a parser. [ParSec](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html) will do fine for smaller examples, and you get much more readable and flexible code.

Comment: Or Attoparsec depending on your needs (speed vs flexibility/error messages)